# Записать данные из select option в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Мне нужно из select данные которые в опциях записать в БД. Сейчас у меня записывается только value. Но мне нужно и текст который в нем записать в бд в отдельную колонку. Значения в select у меня тянутся с одной таблицы wp_rel_cat, а записываться должны в другую wp_rel_eq

```
function rel_select(){
     global $wpdb;
     $table_cat = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_cat';
    $rel_cat = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT name FROM $table_cat");
?>
 <select name="cat-select">
<option value="">Select category</option>
<?php
foreach($rel_cat as $key => $value):
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<?php
//$results = $wpdb->get_results("INSERT INTO wp_rel_eq (`relcat`)  SELECT name FROM wp_rel_cat");
} ?>


<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_eq';
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'title' => $_POST['title'], 
        'url' => $_POST['url'], 
        'relcat' => $_POST['cat-select'],
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce'] ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: Зачем дублировать информацию в БД? Вы должны записывать только ссылку. А описание, когда будет нужно, подтягивать из другой таблицы

Comment: у меня связка категории которая в select с другими данными в таблице в которую нужно записывать

Comment: Я не знаю другого варианта как можно описание подтягивать к этому ж id из select

Comment: Вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос. Зачем Вам дублирование информации?

Comment: Вам известна операция `JOIN`, которая служит для выборки данных из нескольких таблиц одновременно?

Comment: нет. впервые слышу. Сейчас почитаю. спасибо

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно присваивать одну и ту же категорию из select например к нескольким id другой таблицы. с помощью JOIN можно это сделать?